# Which spells are not impaired by MoC?

Tags: dark-age-of-camelot

The [realm ability](http://www.darkageofcamelot.com/content/realm-abilities) **Mastery of Concentration** has the following description:

> Grants a 100% bonus to avoid being interrupted by any form of attack when casting a spell. The effect of the spell cast will be reduced to the percentages listed. (Necro version transfers to the pet)

I wonder which spells are *not* impaired?

- AFAIK it doesn’t reduce the effect of instant casts. Is this correct?
- Bubbles are probably not affected
- What about self buffs and/or conc buffs? Or buffs like damage shield, PoM/PoT, damage add?
- What about HoT (Heal over Time)?
- What about casting pets while MoC is active? Differences between Theurgist’s temporary pets and permanent pets (Enchanter etc.)? Any special rules for Animist’s mushrooms?
- What about resurrections?